# NewRelic- java agent is not showing GC Pause time, how can we get it?

Tags: java, newrelic

in NewRelic where we could able to see the GC pause times, currently GC cpu usage only shown.

Comment: It's available for GO application,see https://newrelic.com/application-monitoring/features/edition

Comment: but my application is based on java(jvm)